# `fill_null` in Polars DataFrame by sampling the rest of the column?

Tags: python, python-polars

How would you `fill_null` in a `DataFrame` by sampling the rest of the column for a unique value each time a null is occurred?

Example: Suppose I have this `DataFrame`:

```
>>> daf=pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,2, None, None, 5, 6, None, None, None, 10], "b":[None, "two", "three", None, "five", "six", "seven", None, "nine", "ten"]})
>>> daf
shape: (10, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ a    ┆ b     │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ null  │
│ 2    ┆ two   │
│ null ┆ three │
│ null ┆ null  │
│ 5    ┆ five  │
│ 6    ┆ six   │
│ null ┆ seven │
│ null ┆ null  │
│ null ┆ nine  │
│ 10   ┆ ten   │
└──────┴───────┘
```

I'd like to fill the nulls in all columns by sampling the rest of the column. For example, the nulls in "a" should get a random value from [1,2,5,6,10], and the nulls in "b" should get a random value from ["two", "three", "five", "six", "seven", "nine", "ten"]. But there shouldn't be `str` in "a" or `i64` in "b". And the value used to fill the null shouldn't be the same for each null in a column.

I was able to do it by looping over the columns using a standard Python `for` loop:

```
>>> for c in daf.columns:
...   repl=daf[c].drop_nulls().sample(daf[c].len(), with_replacement=True)
...   daf=daf.with_columns(pl.col(c).fill_null(repl))
...
>>> daf
shape: (10, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b     │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ two   │
│ 2   ┆ two   │
│ 1   ┆ three │
│ 2   ┆ six   │
│ 5   ┆ five  │
│ 6   ┆ six   │
│ 5   ┆ seven │
│ 10  ┆ two   │
│ 5   ┆ nine  │
│ 10  ┆ ten   │
└─────┴───────┘
```

but I was trying to figure out how to do it using expressions, and couldn't get it. Is there a way to do this in a more compact way, using the Polars expression syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

This seems to work. It's based on your original idea, it just does the same operations to each column purely with expressions.

```
daf.select(
    pl.col("*").fill_null(
        pl.col("*").drop_nulls().sample(pl.len(), with_replacement=True)
    )
)
```

```
┌─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b     │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ two   │
│ 2   ┆ two   │
│ 6   ┆ three │
│ 10  ┆ six   │
│ 5   ┆ five  │
│ 6   ┆ six   │
│ 1   ┆ seven │
│ 2   ┆ two   │
│ 2   ┆ nine  │
│ 10  ┆ ten   │
└─────┴───────┘
```

### Explanation

`pl.col("*")` (or `pl.all()`) just selects each column individually and applies the subsequent operation to it. Later on it retains the same structure, because for example this works:

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [100, 200, 300]})
>>> df.select(pl.col("*").mul(pl.col("*").mean()))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b       │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ f64 ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ 2.0 ┆ 20000.0 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 40000.0 │
│ 6.0 ┆ 60000.0 │
└─────┴─────────┘
```

If I use a `LazyFrame` and `explain`, this is what it does under the hood:

```
>>> daf.select(pl.col("*").fill_null(pl.col("*").drop_nulls().sample(pl.len(), with_replacement=True))).explain()
 SELECT [col("a").fill_null([col("a").drop_nulls().sample([len()])]), col("b").fill_null([col("b").drop_nulls().sample([len()])])] FROM
  DF ["a", "b"]; PROJECT 2/2 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```

What was a bit surprising to me that the `fill_null` part actually works. The [documentation](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html) for `fill_null` is not very clear on the fact that you can pass an expression to it that returns something else than a single value and it works this way.

Also one would think that using `1` or `100` instead of `pl.len()` would result to the same, but no. `1` returns the same sample for each null replacement, and value any other than `1` or `pl.len()` gives a shape error.

It seems to do a table-sized `or` operation and replace every null value with the value from the corresponding spot from the other side (which can still be null), which is kind of interesting.

```
>>> daf.select(pl.col("*").fill_null(pl.col("*").reverse()))
shape: (10, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ a    ┆ b     │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ ten   │
│ 2    ┆ two   │
│ null ┆ three │
│ null ┆ seven │
│ 5    ┆ five  │
│ 6    ┆ six   │
│ null ┆ seven │
│ null ┆ three │
│ 2    ┆ nine  │
│ 10   ┆ ten   │
└──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! I think one thing that was confusing me was `pl.col("*")`; I couldn't figure out if using it the second time would refer to the original column selected by the first `pl.col("*)`, or if it would create a pairwise loop.

I did notice that the length had to equal the original length, but I hadn't picked up that it was doing an `or`. That's fine for my purposes, though. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about `pl.col("*")` either, but empirical testing is always fun. Added an explanation of the query that it does behind the scenes. Now that I think of it, `or` isn't quite the right word. Maybe `right if left is None else left` is how it is done in the reality, but however.

Comment: `or` makes sense to me FWIW; I feel like that's pretty common. For example, most `Optional`-types I've seen in other language use the word `or` in their methods that do this sort of thing (Java has `orElse`, Scala has `getOrElse`, Rust has `unwrap_or`, etc.).


The other option would be "Ternary Operator" which is closer to what you wrote with your if statement. Either way, thanks for the help!